# Check sentiment of user in AWS Lex

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

How do we check user sentiment in AWS Lex by checking what user has said? Is there any built-in functionality available in Lex or some other AWS service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer I can think of right away is to use an NLP library such as TextBlob. You can read the entire documentation [here](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/). It is very simple and easy to use. The documentation is also pretty good.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
user_input = "What the user had said goes here"
blob = textBlob(user_input)
print(blob.sentiment) #this gives both subjectivity and polarity.
```

Comment: don't know why I am getting below error when I install TextBlob:
No module named _sqlite3

Comment: How are you trying to install it? I recommend using easy_install

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the new service from AWS called "[Amazon Comprehend](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-comprehend-continuously-trained-natural-language-processing/)". This should address your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use solutions from the AWS marketplace [like this](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B072MPBGY3) which are good for small amounts of analysis.